# hazelcast tomcat session not loading classes from app context

Tags: session, tomcat, hazelcast

I'm trying to implement hazelcast session on tomcat server.
I have put in tomcat7/lib the following jars:
hazelcast-tomcat8-sessionmanager-1.0.3.jar,
hazelcast-3.7.4.jar and hazelcast-client-3.7.4.jar.
In tomcat8/conf/server.xml i have:

```
<Listener className="com.hazelcast.session.ClientServerLifecycleListener" />
```

and in tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml:

```
<Manager className="com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionManager"
            clientOnly="true"/>
```

It seems everything starts fine, but when I access the app I get:

```
 29-Dec-2016 16:24:08.073 SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-8] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error processing arequest
 com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.ui.savedrequest.SavedRequest
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:251)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:600)
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSession.deserializeMap(HazelcastSession.java:141)
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSession.readData(HazelcastSession.java:127)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:151)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:104)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:54)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:172)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toObject(ClientProxy.java:186)
        at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.getInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:247)
        at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:240)
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionManager.findSession(HazelcastSessionManager.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.isRequestedSessionIdValid(Request.java:2381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:1250)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:935)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:523)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.ui.savedrequest.SavedRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:151)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:120)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:358)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)
        ... 26 more
```

Anybody has a clue about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Apparently `spring-security-web-xxx.jar` is missing in your classpath/lib. The `HazelcastSessionManager` has a dependency on this jar.

Comment: Which Tomcat version are you using? 8.0.39 or 8.5.x?

Comment: the app is working perfectly without hazelcast.It's an app working for 5 years in production and it's has all the dependencies.

Comment: tomcat recommended by tomcat-session, meaning 8.0.36.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I've just noticed that you define `<Manager>` element in `tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml` but hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager page (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager#deploying-client-server-for-tomcat) says that it should be defined in `$CATALINA_HOME$/conf/context.xml`. Can you please try that and see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something changes your current thread's context `ClassLoader` so Hazelcast's serialization service cannot find the classes. I have created an [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager/issues/13) for this on Hazelcast Tomcat Session Manager's GitHub repository. You can track the progress there.

Edit:
Can you please replace `hazelcast-tomcat8-sessionmanager-1.0.3.jar` with the JAR on [this page](https://github.com/emre-aydin/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager/releases/tag/v1.0.4-FIX) that includes a tentative fix for the issue and let me know if it solves the problem?

Comment: i think now it sees corect ClassLoader.But i have another issue now.I also have hazelcast level 2 cache implemented in the app.I got this now:`SEVERE: Hazelcast Client could not be created. 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type id must be positive! Current: -200, Serializer: com.hazelcast.hibernate.serialization.Hibernate3CacheKeySerializer@6d6646ac
 at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.register(AbstractSerializationService.java:346)
 `

Comment: It seems hazelcast scans jars in classpath for class serializers, and it founds those on hazelcast-hibernate and throws the error.

Comment: @dinulaurentiu your new problem seems to be the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637634/hazelcast-hibernate-spring-in-payara-glassfish-environment-type-id-must-be and this issue (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate4/issues/3) on an old GitHub repository. I will create a new issue in official Hazelcast Hibernate plugin GitHub repository to fix this problem as well.